# Single word request: something does not disconfirm the superiority of the most widely used practice

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, academic-writing

I analysed different nonoperative management practices and all of them showed worse outcomes than surgery.

**The sentence I am writing:**

> None of the nonoperative management practices **disconfirms** the superiority of surgery.

Is "disconfirm" the correct word to use or there are better options?

Comment: Why not "Analysis of the nonoperative management practices confirms the superiority of surgery." which avoids the double negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would re-phrase the sentence, as your focus is on the result which you are trying to express namely

**I analysed different nonoperative management practices and all of them showed worse outcomes than surgery.**

Then I would suggest

**Nonoperative management practices are unable to disprove the superiority of surgery.**

However looking at this I would suspect that the answer cannot be true. Unless you relate the answer and the objective of the originator. (which I can only guess at).

Example

*Nonoperative management practices are unable to disprove the superiority of surgery in* **this case**

*Nonoperative management practices are unable to disprove the superiority of surgery* **with regard to the management of blunt force trauma to the spleen**

**disprove**
verb [ T ]
UK  /dɪˈspruːv/ US  /dɪˈspruːv/

to prove that something is not true:

Comment: Refute is also possible, as a synonym for disprove.